# PhantomJs получить траффик от страницы

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Открываем страницу в PhantomJs, страница делает множество Ajax-запросов к серверу.
Как узнать содержание ответов от сервера ?

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов а что Вы думаете по поводу переопределения  XMLHTTPRequest в document до начала работы скриптов самого документа ? Я еще не очень разобрался с phantomjs- возможно ли это? (В настоящий момент пишу прокси для запросов)

Comment: Блин. Кучу времени убил на это http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474462/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B2-xmlhttprequest и в итоге оказалось, что в фантоме какой-то странный XHR, в нем onreadystatechange - unconfigurable сеттер/геттер объекта XHR, а не прототипа, как например в Хроме в котором Blink :(((