# Как перехватить ответ сервера в XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Можно ли имея возможность изменить (inject) XMLHttpRequest изменить его так, чтобы можно было перехватить содержимое ответа не подменяя целиком весь объект со всеми его методами ?
Предполагается, что далее в коде будут вызовы вроде:

```
x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open( "GET", "/" );
x.onreadystatechange = function () {...};
x.send( null );
```

или даже с учетом однопоточности:

```
x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open( "GET", "/" );
x.send( null );
x.onreadystatechange = function () {...};
```

Comment: если посмотрите _onreadystatechange_ это метод объекта, а не прототипа

Comment: а где вы увидели _onreadystatechange [native]_?

Comment: на самом деле там это как-то все очень интересно устроено :-) попробую вечером поразбираться

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32951/discussion-between-grundy-and-reinraus).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Решение для Blink

Blink - это Chrome, Opera etc.

В прототипе `XMLHttpRequest` `onreadystatechange` объявлен как геттер/сеттер и задавая свой геттер/сеттер нужно не сломать логику работы `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
var oldXMLHttpRequest = XMLHttpRequest;

XMLHttpRequest = function() {
    var xhr = new oldXMLHttpRequest();
    // получаем дескриптор прототипных setter/getter
    var descrGetSet = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(
        Object.getPrototypeOf( xhr ),
        "onreadystatechange" );
    
    var newSet = function( val ) {
        console.log ( "setter" );
        descrGetSet.set.call( xhr, function() { // прототипный setter
             console.log( "Inject "+this.status ); // this.responseText
             return val.apply( xhr, arguments );
        } );
    }
    
   Object.defineProperty( xhr, "onreadystatechange", {
        set: newSet, // новый setter
        get: descrGetSet.get // старый getter
   } );
   
   return xhr;
}
```

Теперь сделав:

```
x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open( "GET", "/" );
x.send( null )
x.onreadystatechange = function () { console.log( this.statusText+' is 2' )};
```

Увидим

```
Inject 200
OK is 2
Inject 200
OK is 2
Inject 200
OK is 2
```

Что и должно быть при смене `readyState`.

---

## Решение для Webkit

Webkit - Safari, PhantomJS

Проблема в этом движке- `onreadystatechange` это геттер/сеттер объекта `XHR`, а не `XHR.prototype`. В итоге переопределить его нельзя. Унаследоваться от `XHR` тоже нельзя, поэтому нужно применять обертку для `XHR`.
Весьма хороша эта обертка:
https://github.com/ilinsky/xmlhttprequest